# How do I store a mongojs query result to a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs, nosql

All i get from this code:

var views = db.books.find({"number":1}, {"views":1, _id:0});
console.log(views);

is this response:

```
{ _readableState:
  { highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: [],
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: false,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    calledRead: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    objectMode: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
 readable: true,
 domain: null,
 _events: {},
 _maxListeners: 10,
 _get: [Function] }
```

Comment: i've been stuck in this module for days now...any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.findOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#find-first-occurence-with-findone) to return a single instance and get the result.

[Find](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#making-queries-with-find) assumes you're querying for a collection of documents and return a cursor:

You can for example, convert it to an array:

```
db.books.find({"number":1}, {"views":1, _id:0}).toArray(function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

You can use `.each` to iterate through elements and `.nextObject` to get the next, they're all asynchronous obviously being IO operations in nodejs, here is [the section on cursors in the manual](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#cursors).

Comment: thanks! now how do i parse the result using node.js?

Comment: Sure, you sounded really desperate in that comment :) What `results` returns is just a JavaScript array. You handle it like you would any other type of array. If this answer solved your issue please consider accepting it.

Comment: Doesn't it return an array of JSON texts?